# Order of operation int(4*x/y) vs int(x/(y/4))

Tags: c++, int, expression, operator-precedence

Suppose x and y are of type int.

Are the two expressions:

```
int(4*x/y)
```

and:

```
int(x/(y/4))
```

always evaluate to the same for all `x` and `y` of type `int`? They should mathematically, but only the second expression is consistent (i.e., producing the expected value) in a program I've written.

Comment: You have tagged your question with everything except the programming language this is in. It might have some relevance to the question.

Comment: No, they should not, mathematically, evaluate to the same value, once you are working with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many programming languages, `4*x/y` and `x/(y/4)` are different because `y/4`, an integer, is the truncated result of the division of `y` by `4`. No such truncation exists in `4*x/y`. On obvious difference in when `y` is `1`, in which case the second expression divides by zero, whereas the first one computes `4*x`.

Comment: Good point. I should have stated that when y is a nonzero multiple of 4. I think in my case I had y=4 and x=1, and the first expression gave me 0 while the second expression gave me 1. It leads me to speculate that division (x/y) happens before multiplication (4*x/y).

Comment: @YifengXu At the other end of the spectrum, `4*x` may overflow whereas  `x/(y/4)` rarely overflows (only for `y` equal to `-4` and `x` equal to `INT_MIN`. If your compiler gave you 0 for `4*x/y` with y=4 and x=1, get another compiler.

Comment: why does x/(y/4) overflows when y=-4 and x=INT_MIN? Is it because -INT_MIN is outside the capacity of int while INT_Min isn't? Thank you.

Comment: @YifengXu - correct, at least assuming a two's complement system.  It can't overflow at all if using sign-magnitude.

Comment: And is INT_MIN negative? If so, is INT_MAX = -INT_MIN - 1? Thanks.

Comment: `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` need not have any specific relationship, pedantically speaking.  In practice, `INT_MIN` is usually `-INT_MAX - 1` (note - not the same as what you wrote).

Comment: @YifengXu (Assuming 2's complement) Mathematically, yes, but not programmatically. Programmatically, `-INT_MIN` is undefined behavior (because it overflows).

Answer (score 1):

i assume x and y are ints

then of course not :)
on integers: x/4=floor(x/4) mathematically

which gives you:

floor(4*x/y)
and
floor(x/floor(y/4))

Comment: Right. but what about y=4 and x=1. Both should gave me 1, right? But the first expression gave me 0.

Comment: c++ operator precedence put division and multiplication to the same class...in this case if it chooses / first than 4*(1/4)=4*0

Comment: @ZoltánNagy A sequence of multiplications and divisions must be executed left-to-right. The relevant part of the C99 standard is the grammar in 6.5.5:1 and C++ is no different.

Comment: my compiler gives 1...which according to Pascal Cuoq is by the book..what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++ compiler in linux

Comment: Interestingly I also got 1 for both when I tried again, but the first one gave me 0 a few days ago using a different machine. (but y was something like query.size() where query is a vector)